# Summing values of a dice until a 6 occurs

Tags: probability, expectation, dice

A dice is rolled and it's values are summed until a 6 occurs. You can stop at any time and take your profit (the sum of the values) with you, however, as soon as a 6 occurs, it'll be decreased to zero and the game ends.

Now consider strategy $H_k$, where you stop if you reach a value of $\ge k$ or as soon as a six occurs.

Find the value of $k$, for which the profit is maximal. In other words: For which $k$ is the gain per game not positive anymore?

Comment: What have you tried?  I suggest simulating the game first.  That should be easy enough and will give you a good sense of the answer.  Should say: it's not obvious to me that your two questions are equivalent.  It's hard to have intuition, but I wouldn't be surprised if the expected profit peaks for some $k$ and then starts to decline again.

Comment: Oh, I think I misread your second question.  You are asking for the $k$ from which you begin to decline.  Now I agree with you that they are equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

If the expected value of the next roll is positive then roll again, otherwise stop.

Let $k$ be the current profit. Then the expected value of the next roll is

$$\frac{1+2+3+4+5-k}{6}$$

and it's clear that this is zero when $k=15$.

So, if $k\le14$, roll again; if $k=15$ it doesn't matter whether you roll again; if $k\ge16$, stop.

Strategy $H_{15}$ or $H_{16}$ will maximize profit in the long run. A simulation confirms this and suggests the maximal profit per game is about $6.15$.